# Powershell being too clever

Tags: powershell

Apologies for what is probably a newbish question.

I am writing some Powershell scripts that run various queries against AD. They will usually return a bunch of results, which are easy to deal with, ie:

```
$results = myQuery
write-host "Returned " + $results.Count + " results."
foreach ($result in $results) { doSomething }
```

No worries. However, if there is only 1 result, Powershell automagically translates that result into a single object, rather than an array that contains 1 object. So the above code would break, both at the Count and the foreach. I'm sure the same problem would occur with 0 results.

Could someone suggest an elegant way to handle this? Perhaps some way to cast the results so they are always an array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the first line of code to

```
$results = @(myQuery)
```

This will always return an array.  See [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell.aspx) for additional details.

Comment: Could you tell me why it was designed like this? My colleague asked and I didn't know..

Comment: The blog entry referenced above explains in some detail.

Comment: The @ means "string literal" in C#.  I guess it means "array literal" here.

Comment: Pretty certain it's not Powershell - I think it's AD itself. When I do LDAP queries in VBScript, it returns an array for multiple values, a single object for a single user, and (I think) a null string for a null value.

VERY annoying.

Make sure you check what happens if the query matches nothing.

Comment: @ChristianLinnell: That's certainly PowerShell. You can try with `(1..5|?{$_-eq3}).count`. The point is that *usually* in PowerShell when assigning a query that results in only a single value you want to value while when returning collections you use pipelines to process them. In fact, I have very rarely written a `foreach` loop in PowerShell so far and I see this mostly from people who have experience in C# or Java and try verbatim code translation to PS. In my opinion `$x=foo; foreach($y in $x){...}` is unidiomatic and the normal way would be `foo|foreach{...}`. You have a pipeline. Use it!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the foreach works just fine. All uses of foreach (the foreach keyword, the Foreach-Object cmdlet, and Foreach-Object's aliases "foreach" and "%") all have the same behavior of "wrapping" the object in question in an array if needed. Thus, all uses of foreach will work with both scalar and array values.

Annoyingly, this means they work with null values too. Say I do:

```
$x = $null
foreach ($y in $x) {Write-Host "Hello world 1"}
$x | Foreach-Object {Write-Host "Hello world 2"}
```

I'll get

```
"Hello world 1"
"Hello world 2"
```

out of that.

Answer (score 0):

This has bitten me as well. No clever ideas on how to fix `$results.Count`, but the foreach can be fixed by switching to a pipeline.

```
$scalar = 1
$list = (1,2)
$list | % { $_ }
```

prints
1
2

```
$scalar | % { $_ }
```

prints
1