# Getting the count of a hashtable that only has one key/value in it

Tags: powershell, count, hashtable

I have a foreach loop that currently puts three entries in my hashtable:

```
$result = foreach($key in $serverSpace.Keys){
    if($serverSpace[$key] -lt 80){
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Server = $key
            Space = $serverSpace[$key]}}}
```

When I use

```
$result.count
```

I get 3 as expected.
I changed the foreach loop to exlude the entries less than or equal to one using

```
$result = foreach($key in $serverSpace.Keys){
    if($serverSpace[$key] -lt 80 -and $serverSpace[$key] -gt 1){
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Server = $key
            Space = $serverSpace[$key]}}}
```

$result.count should have 1 as its output but it doesn't recognize .count as a suggested command and $result.count doesn't output anything anymore. I'm assuming when theres only one entry in the hash table it won't allow a count? Not sure whats going on but my conditions for my script are dependent on the count of $result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Force it to be an array: `@($result).count`

Comment: [1] that PSCO is NOT a hashtable. [*grin*] [2] if you want a single object to have a `.Count` property, you need to make that object into a collection. the easiest way is to prefix the $Var name with `[array]`.

Comment: Oh wow I'm dumb. That makes sense. Thank you to both of you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell being too clever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913788/powershell-being-too-clever)

Comment: Terminology note: What your `foreach` loop is returning is one or more _custom objects_ (`[pscustomobject]` instances), not [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

Answer (score 2):

$result is not a hashtable so I prefixed it with @($result).count. Thank you to @Theo and @Lee_Dailey

Answer (score 1):

**What you're seeing is a *bug* in *Windows PowerShell*** (as of the latest *and final* version, 5.1), which has since been corrected in [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) - see [GitHub issue #3671](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3671) for the original bug report.

That is, **since v3 *all* objects should have an [intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) `.Count` property , not just *collections***, in the interest of unified treatment of scalars and collections - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) for more information.

The **workaround for *Windows PowerShell*** is indeed to force a value to be an *array* **via `@(...)`**, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), which is guaranteed to have a `.Count` property, as shown in your answer, but it **shouldn't be necessary and indeed isn't anymore in *PowerShell (Core, v6+)***

```sh
# !! Due to a BUG, this outputs $null in *Windows PowerShell*,
# !! but correctly outputs 1 in PowerShell (Core).
([pscustomobject] @{}).Count

# Workaround for Windows PowerShell that is effective in *both* editions,
# though potentially wasteful in PowerShell (Core):
@([pscustomobject] @{}).Count
```